# greek character of GFS Porson is missing with LuaLaTeX (fontspec, polyglossia)

Tags: luatex, fontspec, polyglossia, greek

When I LuaLaTeXify a document with GFS Porson as greek font, it doesn't print the Greek semicolon (·) when written as ·, it uses the latin semicolon when written as ;. If I am right, · is `\symbol{0387}`, which prints nothing, too, the same holds true for \anoteleia. It works with GFS Didot and many other fonts, but not with GFS Porson, though I have all files from TeXlive (in the document: GFSPorson.luc and GFSPorson.otf are used)

PS: With pdflatex (babel ...) there were no problems.

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
% \RequirePackage{suffix,xstring}
\documentclass{scrbook}
% \RequirePackage{xargs,cmap,xpatch}
% \input{glyphtounicode.tex}\pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage{luainputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}[Style = Alternate, Ligatures = {Common, {TeX}}]
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}[Ligatures = {TeX}]
\usepackage{polyglossia} % babel doesn't help
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant = ancient]{greek}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
blablabla 
\selectlanguage{greek}
ΣΩ.\quad Οὑτωσὶ τοίνυν, ὦ παῖ καλέ, ἐννόησον; ὁ μὲν πρότερος ἦν λόγος
Φαίδρου τοῦ Πυθοκλέους, Μυρρινουσίου ἀνδρός\symbol{0387} ὃν δὲ μέλλω λέγειν
Στησιχόρου τοῦ Εὐφήμου, Ἱμεραίου. λεκτέος δὲ ὧδε· ὅτι οὐκ ἔστ’\,ἔτυμος
λόγος ὃς ἂν παρόντος ἐραστοῦ τῷ μὴ ἐρῶντι φῇ δεῖν χαρίζεσθαι\anoteleia{} ὁ
μὲν μαίνεται, ὁ δὲ σωφρονεῖ.
\end{document}
```

Comment: · is middle dot, not a Greek character

Comment: Yesnoyes, the greek semicolon looks like this, and it is even a character on my Greek keyboard. The Wise Wikiped say "Σε λειτουργικό σύστημα Microsoft Windows [...]  Alt + 0903 ή Alt + 0183. Στο πολυτονικό πληκτρολόγιο: ALT + Shift + ]. Σε [...] Mac OS X και Linux χρησιμοποιείται ο συνδυασμός AltGr + Q."<--that's how I type it

Comment: And from the Unicode Charts: "0387 · GREEK ANO TELEIA
• functions in Greek like a semicolon
• 00B7  ·   is the preferred character
≡ 00B7  ·   middle dot"

Comment: Could you simplify your code to only include what you're asking about? The code as it is now seems to contain a lot of stuff that has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann I copied the character from your question.

Comment: If you continue to have problems with this character, you should try inputting it as `\char"0387` rather than as `\symbol{0387}`.

Comment: @Sverre: I'll do it. I tried it without each of the packages and all of them together, but finally I included them -- in case a solution would interfere with one of them.

Comment: @Mico: Yours is so far the only way it works. Is there a way to tell lualatex, that ; in the Greek part of the document means \char"0387{}? Babel has \addtoextraspolutonikogreek, but polyglossia.sty doesn't.

Comment: You can probably go much further. For instance, there's isn't a single word of German in your document, so what does ``\setmainlanguage{german}`` do there? Does your problem disappear if you remove that code? If not, don't include it here. The same applies to the rest of your code. Please read the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Comment: Sadly, my knowledge of Greek -- classical or modern -- is virtually nil. (I had to download and install the font `GFS Porson` first before I was able to compile your code.) I'm afraid I'm in no position to offer advice on how to employ `polyglossia`'s capabilities for your purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character exists, provided you use the correct Unicode point (U+0387)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}[Style = Alternate, Ligatures = {Common,TeX}]
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}[Ligatures = TeX]

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant = ancient]{greek}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}
Οὑτωσὶ^^^^0387

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need `·` (U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT) and you're worried about this strange conversion, you can do

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{·}{^^^^0387} % the character is U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT
```

Some more information. It appears that U+00B7 is [the “preferred character” in place of U+0387](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf) (the reason is unknown and mysterious to me), so some software seems to arbitrarily do the conversion. The font GFS Porson hasn't been updated like other GFS fonts (Artemisia, Baskerville, Bodoni, Complutum, Didot, Neohellenic and Solomos), so it has nothing in U+00B7.

My Emacs doesn't change the character, so that's why my example compiles correctly, while copying from here doesn't.

Comment: Strange -- now I copied your semicolon-dot-character, but it still doesn't work. PS: My system is Ubuntu-Linux, my editor is emacs, though I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann Curious, but it seems that this site (and not only it) transforms the character into U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT. I tried a few times copying and pasting it.

Comment: It works! (at least with the newunicodechar-command) I'm really sorry that they don't update GFS Porson, which lacks many features like boldface etc. It is (not only) my favorite font, all of the Greek Loeb library (Harvard UP) is written in the (almost identical) Zeph Greek, with worse kerning.